# Targeting PictureBox in 2D array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a PictureBox array that creates a 10,10 grid of pictures, how can I taget one of those pictureboxes?

```
Public Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Dim active As Boolean = True
Dim images(8) As Image 'declares image array

Dim zonesY As Integer = 10
Dim zonesX As Integer = 100

Dim Guy As Object

Dim generator As New Random
' Dim x As Integer  'declares x as an integer variable
' Dim y As Integer  'declares y as an integer variable
Dim oGrid(zonesX, zonesY) As PictureBox

Private Sub SetupGrid()
    images(0) = Image.FromFile("clear.png")
    images(1) = Image.FromFile("1.png")
    images(2) = Image.FromFile("2.png")
    images(3) = Image.FromFile("3.png")
    images(4) = Image.FromFile("4.png")
    images(5) = Image.FromFile("5.png")
    images(6) = Image.FromFile("blank.png")
    images(7) = Image.FromFile("hit.png")
    images(8) = Image.FromFile("mine.png")

    For y As Integer = 1 To zonesY 'starts a For loop (1 to zonesY number of loops)
        For x As Integer = 1 To zonesX  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)
            Dim zonesize1 As Integer
            Dim zonesize2 As Integer

            Dim blockStatus As Integer
            Dim allZones As Integer
            allZones = zonesX * zonesY
            blockStatus = generator.Next(0, allZones)

            oGrid(x, y).Name = x & ", " & y

            MsgBox(oGrid(x, y).Name)

            If blockStatus < (allZones / 5) Then
                oGrid(x, y).Tag = True
                If oGrid(x, y).Tag = True Then
                    oGrid(x, y).Image = images(8)
                End If
            Else
                oGrid(x, y).Tag = False
                If oGrid(x, y).Tag = False Then
                    oGrid(x, y).Image = images(6)
                End If
            End If
            oGrid(x, y).Height = 16
            oGrid(x, y).Width = 16
            zonesize1 = oGrid(x, y).Height 'sets out all of the boxes on the form.
            zonesize2 = oGrid(x, y).Width
            oGrid(x, y).Left = ((x - 1) * zonesize1 + 15)
            oGrid(x, y).Top = ((y - 1) * zonesize2 + 15)
            Me.Controls.Add(oGrid(x, y))
            '  Wire this control up to an appropriate event handler
            AddHandler oGrid(x, y).Click, AddressOf pbxNewZoneClicked

        Next
    Next

    Me.Height = 500   'sets the height of fmmGame
    Me.Width = 500  'sets the width of frmGame

End Sub



Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SetupGrid()

End Sub

Private Sub CheckHits()
    Dim FicX1 As Integer = zonesX - 1
    Dim FicY1 As Integer = zonesY - 1

    Dim counter As Integer = 0

End Sub

Private Sub pbxNewZoneClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If active = True Then
        Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

        Dim splitName() As String = pb.Name.Split(",")
        Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(splitName(0))
        Dim y As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(splitName(1))

        Dim Status As String = "Clear" ' Status - Testing Purposes Only
        If pb.Tag = True Then ' Status - Testing Purposes Only
            Status = "Mine" ' Status - Testing Purposes Only
        End If
        ' MsgBox(pb.Name & vbCrLf & "Status: " & Status, , "Test") ' Post Statistics of box.


        Dim counter As Integer = 0


        If oGrid(x, y).Tag = True Then
            pb.Image = images(7) ' Hit Image
            active = False
            ' MsgBox("No Longer Active", , "Test") ' Testing Purposes Only
        ElseIf oGrid(x, y).Tag = False Then
            pb.Image = images(counter) ' Clear Image by default.
        End If

    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

I'm trying to check if the picturebox up one, and left one's tag = True to += 1 the counter.

Comment: Target? Please explain what you are trying to do? Is this a user interaction issue, or a image bookkeeping issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out these lines:

```
'Dim x As Integer  'declares x as an integer variable
'Dim y As Integer  'declares y as an integer variable
```

Change this line:

```
Dim oGrid(zonesX, zonesY) As PictureBox
```

Change your loops to this:

```
For y As Integer = 1 To zonesY 'starts a For loop (1 to zonesY number of loops)
  For x As Integer = 1 To zonesX  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)
    '// blah-blah
  Next
Next
```

Add this to your pbxNewZoneClicked:

```
Dim splitName() As String = pb.Name.Split(",")
Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(splitName(0))
Dim y As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(splitName(1))
```

This "should" get your program running.

Is this the best way to do this?  Probably not, but that's a much longer conversation.

Comment: Now when I scroll over oGrid(x, y).Name = x & ", " & y is says oGrid(x,y) is Nothing. Code updated.

Comment: @RickBross What happened to the "oGrid(x, y) = New PictureBox" line?  It's missing now.

Comment: Not sure, it was saying out of bounds of the array, Should I have that?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much to work on.  I looked at your other questions to try to piece it together.

I "think" you want to do something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckHits(ByVal column As Integer, ByVal row As Integer)

  'Above Left:
  If column > 0 And row > 0 Then
    If oGrid(column - 1, row - 1).Tag Then
      counter += 1
    End If
  End If

  'Above:
  If row > 0 Then
    If oGrid(column, row - 1).Tag Then
      counter += 1
    End If
  End If

  '// continue going around the cell
End Sub
```

In your posted code you are referencing a 2nd 2-dim array Picturebox(,) where it looks like you already have everything in the oGrid(,) array.  I'm just using the oGrid array.

Also, you have to check the boundaries.  If you are checking the (0, 0) square, you obviously have to ignore the left and above coordinate since they don't exist in the grid.

Comment: , didn't know you could just slap the .tag on the end of the array. Guess it makes sense, it being a picturebox and all.

Comment: @RickBross Yes, since you have an array of PictureBoxes, you have all of the PictureBox properties available.

Comment: now it just says, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @RickBross Then you didn't associate the array with the actual pictureboxes.  You will have to loop through your pictureboxes and assign them to your oGrid(,) array.  I assumed you were doing that already where in your post you had "OTHER CODE..."

Comment: CODE UPDATED, its copy and pastable, everything is created on runtime.

Comment: I dim the picturebox array above form_load, then oGrid(x, y) = New PictureBox in form_load. Is this wrong to do?